# Cannot transfer files to proftpd server from external ip

Tags: java, ftp

I'm making a basic FTP transfer app that works with my ProFtpd server.

On the local network, the following code works. However, when I use this code and try to connect by external IP, (yes, I changed the IP to my external ip) I get the error:

> sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException: PORT :500 Illegal PORT command, EPSV ALL in effect

In addition, the connection to ftp server in a browser causes a minute or two delay from the external IP, but I don't know if that is related.

Here's my code:

```
URL url=new URL("ftp://"+username+":"+password+"@"+ip+path+recipient+"/"+sendMe.getName());
    URLConnection con=url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("connected");

    FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(sendMe);
    BufferedOutputStream output=new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("output Stream");

    int c;
    int size=0;
    TransferDialog transfer=new TransferDialog("0 bytes processed");

    while ((c = input.read()) != -1) {
        output.write(c);
        size++;
        transfer.changeText(size+" bytes processed");
        System.out.println(size);
    }

    if (input != null) {
        input.close();
    }
    if (output != null) {
        output.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Uploaded");
```

When this runs, the error occurs instead of the "output stream" message. Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: This isn't really a java question, this is about how to configure your FTP server to work properly, and is more a question for serverfault.com (minus the Java bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make an [Active FTP connection](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#active) through your external IP, when there are presumably firewalls in between. You need to initiate a [Passive connection](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#passive) instead which was designed to deal with firewalls and such (since all connections are client-initiated in passive mode).

This worked when you did it *internally* because there were no firewalls between your client and the server. Keep in mind firewalls (in their default configuration) block all non-client initiated TCP connections.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to edit the code to change it from an active connection to a passive one?

Comment: @Jon You haven't shown us that part of the code, but I'm sure you'll be able to figure out by looking it up. This should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: @Jon: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282776/setting-ftp-active-passive-mode-with-java-urlconnection