# What's wrong with this FTP code?

Tags: java, ftp

I'm attempting to use the Java.net.* libraries to access a FTP file. What I'm trying to do is to initialize an InputStream for this file:

ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt

Why doesn't this code work? I keep on getting an IOException.

```
private static void downloadNasdaqList(){
    String nasdaqURL = "ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt";

    try {
        openFTP(new URL(nasdaqURL));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PADailyQuotes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static void openFTP (URL website){ 
    try{
        URLConnection urlc = website.openConnection();
        InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException MUE){
        System.out.println("ERROR: openFTP- Invalid URL");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    catch (IOException IOE){
        System.out.println("ERROR: openFTP - Unable to establish connection");
        System.exit(3);
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with permissions? I wouldn't think so because we could access the page by just copying and pasting the URL into the browser.

Also, if I were interested in using the org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP and org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient libraries, instead, like they do here:

http://codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example

What should I put for server and port for the connect() method and the username and password for the login() method for the file I provided? (This is assuming that the ftp file I linked is indeed public and I have no given username or password.)

Sorry ahead of time if this turns out to be a stupid or repetitive question. I used the search function and followed the other StackOverflow thread to the best of my ability; but, my code still didn't work. Thanks for reading.

EDIT: The specific exception is

> Jul 08, 2014 8:35:03 AM pa.dailyquotes.PADailyQuotes openFTP SEVERE:
>   null java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)...
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at pa.dailyquotes.PADailyQuotes.downloadNasdaqList
>   (PADailyQuotes.java:67)
>     at pa.dailyquotes.PADailyQuotes.main(PADailyQuotes.java:25)

Line 67 is

> br.readLine();  //skip first line

br is a BufferedReader that was not initialized properly from the aforementioned methods.

Comment: Copy the IOException to your question.

Comment: You say it works in the browser; so does that browser have any specific settings like a proxy server?

Comment: @ Gimby You guys are throwing out so many technical terms that it'll take me a day or two to research everything! Hahaha... It's just an ordinary web browser with default settings. Works on Chrome, Opera, Firefox, etc. I just assumed if you can assess some content through the web browser that there must be a way to access the content with Java/Java libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to do a passive FTP connection to make it work through a NAT-router somewhere between your computer and ftp.nasdaqtrader.com.

This cannot easily be done with URLConnection, and you need to use a dedicated FTP library to do so.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282875/53897

Comment: I ended up using the Apache libraries like in the tutorial in my OP. For the username and password for the FTPClient login() method I put "anonymous" and my email address. It turns out this is common login credentials for publicly accessible FTP files. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Connection timed out usually means you can't see the server. Check the server name/IP is configured correctly and try manually FTPing to that server from the computer running the program using a standard FTP client to make sure you can see it.